# Ionic/Angular: Is there a way to trigger ionViewWill/DidEnter from within tab going to outside page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to trigger an event going back into my tab page from a page outside of the routing module.

2.
I have tried:

Using @ionic/angular NavController from both pages:
From tab page:

```
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/store-name-keywords'], {
```

And again from the other page

```
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/tabs/storesearch'], {
          queryParams: { keyword: this.storeNameKeyword, city: city.cityName },
          relativeTo: this.route
        });
```

3.
Here is my code for the tab routing of first app routing and then tab routing

```
  {
    path: 'storesearch',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/store-search/store-search.module').then(
        m => m.StoreSearchPageModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: 'store-search-results',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/store-search-results/store-search-results.module').then(
        m => m.StoreSearchResultsPageModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: 'store-search-results/:keyword/:city',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/store-search-results/store-search-results.module').then(
        m => m.StoreSearchResultsPageModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: 'store-name-keywords',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/store-name-keywords/store-name-keywords.module').then(
        m => m.StoreNameKeywordsPageModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: 'select-prefecture',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/select-prefecture/select-prefecture.module').then(
        m => m.SelectPrefecturePageModule
      )
  },
```

Tab routing all routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'ec',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/ec/ec.module').then(m => m.ECPageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'mypage',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/mypage/mypage.module').then(
                m => m.MyPagePageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'storesearch',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/store-search/store-search.module').then(
                m => m.StoreSearchPageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'storesearch/:keyword',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/store-search/store-search.module').then(
                m => m.StoreSearchPageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'storesearch/:keyword/:city',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/store-search/store-search.module').then(
                m => m.StoreSearchPageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'storesearch/store-search-results',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import(
            '../pages/store-search-results/store-search-results.module'
          ).then(m => m.StoreSearchResultsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'article',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/article/article.module').then(
                m => m.ArticlePageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'qrcode',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/qrcode/qrcode.module').then(
                m => m.QRCodePageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'coupon',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/coupon/coupon.module').then(
                m => m.CouponPageModule
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can always trigger an enter regardless of what you've come from on route enter by subscribing to Angular's ActivatedRoute's url:

```
     import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,

    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(obs => {
  // Can call a method for reentering view here
  this.enteredStoreSearchPage();
});
```

I got this from another answer I'm sure, but just in case this helps anyone, I wanted to post it. Nothing like answering your own question :)